# django,split the query parameter and pass the value in IN cluase

Tags: python, django, postgresql

i have written a native sql query in django, now i need to pass filter condition in where clause.

i am passing the URL as list of values like (a,b,c,d) and in database i need to compare and these with a column and filter the data.

Example URL:

**(//10.100.212.16:8000/test/&param1=a,b,c,d)**

example sql:

select * from test where test like(%a%) or like(%b%) or like(%c%) or like(%d%)

how can write this in django using native sql.

i am using postgres as db

thanks

Comment: It'll be mildly easier to work with this in Django if you can construct your URL as `?param1=a&param1=b...`. Not a big deal, but it would mean you can get your values pre-split by the `GET` `QueryDict` object.

Answer (score 3):

Given the URL as presented, but assuming you're using the correct `?` character rather than `&` to mark the beginning of the querystring:

```
import operator
from django.db.models import Q
param1_raw_string = request.GET.get('param1')
if param1_raw_string:
    param1_values = param1_raw_string.split(',')
    tests = Test.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, (Q(test__contains=param1) for param1 in param1_values)))
else:
    # do something reasonable when param1 is missing
```

If you want case-insensitive comparison, use `__icontains` instead. Composing multiple `Q` objects using `operator.or_` is the main point.

If you use `?param1=a&param1=b...` you can skip the `split` and just write `param1_values = request.GET.getlist('param1')`.

Comment: thanks peter, but my URL is ?param=a,b,c. i used your earlier solution but it is not passing the values in db Query as i am looking ,it is passing as columname like(%a,b%). for example in db it should pass as columname like(%a%) or columname like(%b%)

Comment: Check your `split` return value, then. I've found it useful to drop into the debugger in a view by putting a breakpoint in the view code (`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`) , then running the development server so there's a console for the debugger to use.